# Getting Unauthorized 401 for manifest.json GCM push notifications in ASP.NET

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, manifest.json

My manifest file is in the root folder, referenced in the _Layout view as following:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="~/manifest.json">
```

The file structure is as following:

```
{
"gcm_sender_id": "MY_Sender_Id",
"permissions": [
"gcm"
] 
}
```

Keep getting 401 unauthorized, in chrome dev tools under the application tab, this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Are you positive you're using the correct value for the `gcm_sender_id`?

Comment: @AL. Yes, have even closed an account and created a new one, to get a new sender id just in case the previous one was corrupted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using FCM for Web, the value for `gcm_sender_id` is fixed. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#configure_the_browser_to_receive_messages):

```
{
  "//": "Some browsers will use this to enable push notifications.",
  "//": "It is the same for all projects, this is not your project's sender ID",
  "gcm_sender_id": "103953800507"
}
```

> Don't confuse the "browser sender ID" with the project-specific sender ID value shown in your Firebase project settings. The browser sender ID for **manifest.json** is a fixed value, common among all FCM JavaScript clients.